# How can foreign investment have a negative figure?

Tags: fixed-income, investing, fundamentals

Just looking at

http://www.tradingeconomics.com/japan/foreign-bond-investment

Wondering how can foreign bond investment be negative? You can have 0 investment, you can have positive investment, but how can value of investment be negative? Is it Bank of Japan buying back their own debt?

Edit: I get that it's a cash flow, but that doesn't explain the source of negative cash flows.

Why the down votes? I'm a newbie...

Comment: It's a flow, not a stock; like the difference between income and wealth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a likely multiple source of this indicator becoming negative in general. In this particular case this is probably related to the investment of [Japanese monies in foreign bonds](http://uk.reuters.com/article/2013/10/31/japan-economy-capflow-idUKL3N0IL0O420131031). Which in turn looks to be an effect of the quantitative easing by the Bank of Japan.

Comment: I cannot up vote yet, but thank you for the link. That explains a lot.